# Viewing GCP Cloud Datastore metrics, traces, query plan

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

What tools are there to investigate query performance in Cloud Datastore? I'm interesting in seeing things similar to a SQL query plan or any metrics beyond the total round trip request time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, these insights don't exist.  Cloud Datastore only supports queries where an [index exists](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview).